# puppet how to inherit class

Tags: class, service, puppet, notify

I can't understand how to restart service from another class.
My structure is:

```
# cat init.pp
class nginxrtmp {  
  include nginxrtmp::nginxinstall  
  include nginxrtmp::nginxconfig
}
```

in nginxrtmp::nginxinstall i have service nginx to restart

```
# cat nginxinstall.pp
service {'nginx':
  name => 'nginx.service',
  ensure => 'running',
  enable => 'true',
}
```

And in nginxrtmp::nginxconfig i have *.erb template with config

```
# cat nginxconfig.pp  
  file { '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf':
    * => $resAttributes,
    content => template('nginxrtmp/redhat.nginx.conf.erb'),
    notify  => nginxinstall::Service['nginx'],
  }
```

And my question is, how to restart service nginx described in another class and file *.pp if my template file change

Answer (score 0):

I just found answer myself. Need to write

```
include nginxrtmp::nginxinstall
```

in class with config

Answer (score 0):

You could create a service.pp file that contains the service and then change it to:

```
  # init.pp
  class nginxrtmp {
    contain nginxrtmp::service
    contain nginxrtmp::config

    Class['::nginxrtmp::config']
    ~> Class['::nginxrtmp::service']
  }

  # service.pp
  service { 'nginx':
    name   => 'nginx.service',
    ensure => 'running',
    enable => 'true',
  }

  # config.pp  
  file { '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf':
    *       => $resAttributes,
    content => template('nginxrtmp/redhat.nginx.conf.erb'),
  }
```

Take a look at: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/bgtm.html and this section in regarding to ordering https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/bgtm.html#c-ordering